# How to smooth shading on baked texture?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, shadows

I baked using full render setting since I have a few light sources. I have a rather low-poly arch, how do I smooth the shading on this WITHOUT increasing the # of polygons? I mean I could always just smooth it manually in photoshop but I assume there has to be a way in blender to do this?

[image]

As you can see the shading is very jagged and outlines each face.

I tried turning on smooth setting for shading via tools -> shading, however that removes ALL shadows, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do:

Step o1: Set the shading to smooth.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Step o2: Add an Edge Split modifier and uncheck Edge Angle.

[image]
[image]

Step o3: Tab into Edit Mode, change selection mode to Edges, then select the edges you want to be sharp.

[image]

Step o4: Hit Ctrl + E to bring up the Edges menu and select Mark Sharp. [ The Edge Split modifier uses these marked edges ]

[image]
[image]

Step o5: And bake :]

Tip: You can add a Subdivision Surface modifier **after** the Edge Split modifier for added smoothness and disable it after the bake.